# ERROR 1415: 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have created a stored procedure with one argument. I have made a trigger to call stored procedure. Trigger calls stored procedure on change of a column value  a table(device_session1).If is_active is updated to 'No' then trigger calls stored procedure. I pass that column value in stored procedure and procedure prints it but its giving error when i update column value.

Table-

```
CREATE TABLE `device_session1` (
  `id` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_active` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


insert into device_session1(id,is_active) values ('11','YES');
```

Trigger-

```
Delimiter $$
create trigger after_device_session_update
 after update on device_session1
 For Each Row
 BEGIN 
  IF (NEW.is_active="NO") THEN  
  SET @session_id = new.id;
call new_procedure1(@session_id);
  END IF;
 END;   
 Delimiter;
```

Stored Procedure-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure1`(IN id VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
select concat('id : ',id);
END
```

Comment: Well, you cannot do this. The question is: what are you trying to do here? (Are you e.g. trying to do some logging/debugging?)

Comment: In stored procedure i want to fetch records from table2 where id= (argument id).

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But you cannot do this in/from a trigger - an update updates, and does not return a resultset, so MySQL basically does not know what to do with what your select returns (which is why you get the error). So the question is: what *should* MySQL do with this resultset - or in other words: what do you want to do with this/why do you want to do this (so we might be able to propose a different way to achieve this).